# JQuery hide() and show() not working on IE 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**SOLVED: See the author's comment below: "downgraded my Jquery all the way to 1.0.2 and it worked."**

I have this code that works well on all browsers, except IE 7 and 8 (which a lot of my users use).

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#start").click(function(){ 
    $("#start").hide();
    $("#twin_buttons_1").show();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- start of button selection decision tree -->                    
<div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4"> 
  <button type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-success subscribe_button btn-publish">???</button>
</div>

<div id="selection" class="input-group col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-3">

  <!-- Twin 1st level buttons -->
  <div id='twin_buttons_1' style='display:none;'>
    <br>
    <h2 style='font-weight:bold; color:white'>???</h2>
    <button id='no_magic' class="btn btn-publish">???</button>

    <button id='magic' class="btn btn-publish">???</button>

  </div>
```

Also called bootstrap JS and CSS.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? 2.X does not support Old IE.

Comment: I'd be stunted that such obvious, easy detectable bug occurred with a very mature libray. As xec said check out the browser supported by your version of jQuery.

Comment: @roland, its intentional that jQuery 2.x is not supporting old IE brwsers. Its not a Bug

Comment: @Satpal: definitely that's why I emphasizes the fact to checkout supported browsers for the downloaded version jQuery (if 2.x, well, it's expected).

Comment: JQuery 1.11.1 as from http://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.11.1-rc2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Someone downvoted the question. Care to clarify?

Comment: downgraded my Jquery all the way to 1.0.2 and it worked. Lol.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#twin_buttons_1").hide(0);
    $("#start").on("click", function(){ 
        $("#start").hide();
        $("#twin_buttons_1").show();
    });
});
```

And remove the style tag from the element:

```
<div id='twin_buttons_1'>
    <br>
    <h2 style='font-weight:bold; color:white'>???</h2>
    <button id='no_magic' class="btn btn-publish">???</button>
    <button id='magic' class="btn btn-publish">???</button>
</div>
```

Comment: not working. It would not even execute the .hide(0) function.

Comment: Do you have more libraries working at the same time, apart from jQuery?

Comment: I have bootstrap 3.1.1 (css and js), ckeditor.js ckeditor's jquery.js. I disabled them all when testing but still no luck.

Comment: downgraded my Jquery all the way to 1.0.2 and it worked. Lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is downgrading jQuery to really really old ones. I downgraded my jQuery all the way to 1.0.2 and it worked.